# How to recreate this affect

Tags: video, effects

I would like to know what effects are being used and how it would be possible to recreate the effect.

I'd like to recreate how the effect looks like it starts slow then a sort of sped up but slow motion looking by the way it sort of lags the frames.

I would like to recreate this using NCH video editing software since what is the program I am starting out with for now. [NCH VideoPad](http://www.nchsoftware.com/videopad/)

The clip is from *Out of my mind ft. Nicki Minaj* by B.O.B.

[Very short Clip Link](https://vimeo.com/255855821) or [Longer version](https://youtu.be/9tZZF3Lt7HE?t=3m10s).

Alternative examples:

https://www.youtube.com/DhSzLCCT-As?t=1m20s

Comment: What software are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: In addition to Amob100's comment, could you please describe the effect you are looking to reproduce? This will help other people to find your question later on and helps answerers give you a more tailored answer.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I didn't know how to describe it

Comment: @Daniel Maybe you can try...? Just describe what you see, e.g.: `The effect shows a person in multiple places at the same time` or something like that. Just think how you would describe the effect to a friend. And also: add what software you will be using and what you've tried.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I edited the post.